# Which Sorting technique is below code?

Tags: c++, sorting

What sorting technique is the sorting block below:

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
  in=i;
  for(k=i+1;K<5;k++) {
    if (a[in]>a[k])
      in=k;
  }
  if (in!=i) {
    copy=a[i];
    a[c]=a[in];
    a[in]=copy;
  }
}
```

Comment: Formatting your code nicely will greatly increase the chance of you getting an answer. Also redundant (and obvious) comments do not make the code better, they clutter it

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Thank you ivaylo, will follow the same.

Comment: Please specify language used in tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a selection sort for an array of size 5 that sorts the elements in descending order.